# New AMD R9 270X GPU isn't recognized by Windows 7 x64 - UPDATED

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I just bought a Sapphire Radeon R9 270X graphics card and installed it.

The installer on the driver installation CD it came with only shows [this list of compatible cards](http://puu.sh/hS1Jy/b5b106abbc.jpg) though - it doesn't include the 270X at all. I tried using the CD anyway, and I still ended up (1) not having Windows Aero effects and (2) not having the card show up in Device Manager (it just shows "Video Controller (VGA Compatible)").

So I went on the AMD website and downloaded and installed the latest AMD Catalyst Software Suite (Omega 14.12), but I still have the same problem. I even tried uninstalling all AMD programs/drivers and reinstalling it, to no avail. AMD recognizes my card as "Radeon HD 8XXX Series PCIe (OEM)", which is not correct (it should say "Radeon R9 2XX Series").

I tried the CD again, and it says "installation complete" but that I should view the log for warnings. I did, and it seemed to show no warnings.

What am I doing wrong? Is this just a driver problem, or could it be a hardware issue too?

====================

EDIT 5/23/2015:

Since posting this question I got some advice from Reddit and have done the following:

I installed all available updates for Windows 7, since I had been missing a bunch of updates and I saw on another forum that updating Windows helped someone else.

I ran DDU (Display Driver Uninstaller) to wipe all the existing drivers (since I previously had a Radeon HD 4670) and reinstall AMD's 14.12 Omega driver set. When I restart the computer, the resolution has been reset to 800x600 and Windows now sees my card as "Standard VGA Graphics Adapter" in Device Manager.

I changed the BIOS to tell it to use this graphics card first (previously it had been set to use a non-existent card in a different slot, which is weird but I guess was the default setting and worked before with the previous card).

This is the updated DxDiag result: https://app.box.com/s/ch54yb7s866j8q8eo6vib9pv4baewqza

---

UPDATE 2:

@Ramhound and @tereško thought my issue might be power-related, but I'm starting to think otherwise. On a friend's recommendation, I unplugged both 6-pin PCIE cables from the card and tried turning the computer on like that. The fans did not spin and I did not see a visual output on my monitor on boot. I then tried this again with only one of the 6-pin PCIE cables plugged in and got the same result. Only with both 6-pin PCIE cables plugged into the card did I get both (1) the fans to come on and (2) a visual output on my monitor. To me, this suggests that the card is probably getting sufficient power, but I'm certainly no expert. Does this mean it's likely to be a software problem rather than a hardware one?

===================

UPDATE 3: Since I haven't found a solution either here or on Reddit's /r/techsupport, I guess I'm just going to have to return the card, purchase a different one, and hope for the best.

Comment: Yes, I purchased it from Amazon. I'll add more information to the description since I don't have enough characters.

Comment: Hmm, good catch on the 2009 thing. I've uninstalled all graphics drivers and reinstalled the latest stable ones from AMD twice now, so I'm not sure why they'd say they're from 2009 still. And even if I've been unsuccessful this time, I installed my old card only two years ago (2013, not 2009), although the 4670 did come out in September 2008.

Comment: The Hauppauge card is just my TV card, not my graphics card. The graphics card is a Sapphire Radeon R9 270X 2GB GDDR5 DVI-I/DVI-D/HDMI/DP Dual-X with Boost and OC Version PCI-Express Graphics Card 11217-01-20G.

Comment: I have a Gigabyte GA-970A-UD3 motherboard. How do I go about checking to see if it has video input ports?

And yes, the monitor is plugged into the back of the graphics card with a DVI cable.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely plugged into the card itself, not into the motherboard. I don't have any video input ports on the motherboard (sorry for the confusion).

Comment: The fans on the graphics card do spin, by the way, and I'm pretty confident that it's plugged in correctly. It requires two 6-pin PCIE connectors, so I used a cable that came with my PSU to connect one 8-pin PCIE end to the PSU and then the two 6+2-pin PCIE ends to the GPU itself.

Do you think this is a hardware issue or a software/driver problem?

Comment: Sure.

Here's how it looks at the back of the PSU: https://app.box.com/files/0/f/3665393783/1/f_30526376427

It's the bottom-right-most cable, with 8 pins.

Here's where it connects to the GPU: https://app.box.com/files/0/f/0/1/f_30526379835
Each of those two 6-pin connectors has an additional 2-pin optional connector (so it's a 6+2 but I'm using the 6). That cable came with the Corsair PSU, and I don't see any other relevant cables that would work instead.

Comment: Would it be more helpful for me to unplug it and take pictures of the cable itself, or do you understand the kind of cable I'm talking about?

Comment: Sorry about that - hopefully Imgur will work better: https://imgur.com/a/18piy

Comment: The cable I'm currently using is the one he shows in the video at 3:43 here: https://youtu.be/4aeuBVIGDaE?t=223

Comment: I added this to the main question description, but I experimented with the power connection and the fans only turn on (and I only get a visual output on the monitor) when both PCIE connectors are plugged into the card. It seems to me (very much a non-expert) that this would rule out a power issue, wouldn't it?